# I need help implementing this algorithm for the 1worldsync DAM API

Tags: javascript, vb.net, algorithm, data-integrity

```
public static String calculateRFC2104HMAC(String data, String key)
throws java.security.SignatureException, java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException,
java.security.InvalidKeyException {
String result;
// get an hmac_sha1 key from the raw key bytes javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec

signingKey = new javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), \"HmacSHA256\");

// get an hmac_sha1 Mac instance and initialize with the signing key javax.crypto.Mac

mac = javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance(\"HmacSHA256\"); mac .init(signingKey);

// compute the hmac on input data bytes

byte[] rawHmac = mac .doFinal(data.getBytes());
// base64-encode the hmac

result = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(rawHmac);

result = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(result.trim(),\"UTF-8\");

return result;
}
```

I am having a difficult time implementing this algorithm into Javascript.
I have a example to work with but I am doing something wrong along the way and it never outputs the correct hash_code.

here is the example test case I have to work with.

data:
V2/assets?ipGLN=1234&senderGLN=1234&app_id=3cea2db2&TIMESTAMP=2012-12-
06T13:08:02Z

key: 6b904a0c5ceefa991b2ebc9cfec202b6

Generated Hash Code i.e. result: 4F7rjpsRpR0IEy12EfAFShjS9VOxpisVgb8ywavqRrI%3D

So request URL with hash_code parameter will be:

https://digasset.preprod.1worldsync.com/V2/assets?ipGLN=1234&senderGLN=1234&app_id=3cea2db2&TIMESTAMP=2012-12-06T13:08:02Z&hash_code=4F7rjpsRpR0IEy12EfAFShjS9VOxpisVgb8ywavqRrI%3D

If anyone has any insight into implementing the above correctly, I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is my implementation so far..

```
var temp_test_key = "";
var test_key_bytes = encodeTextToUtf8(test_key);
for(var i = 0;i<test_key_bytes.length;i++)
{
    temp_test_key+= test_key_bytes[i];
}  
var hmac = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(CryptoJS.algo.SHA256,temp_test_key);
hmac.update(test_string);
var hash = hmac.finalize();
var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
document.write(hashInBase64);
```

Thank you.

I have even tried to redo this into vb.net.. but it is still not yeilding the same result..

```
Function SignMessage(key As String, message As String) As Byte()
    Dim encText As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
    Dim btKey() As Byte, btMessage() As Byte
    btKey = encText.GetBytes(key)
    Dim myhmac As New HMACSHA256(btKey)
    btMessage = encText.GetBytes(message)
    Return myhmac.ComputeHash(btMessage)
End Function


Sub Main()
    Dim testString As String = "V2/assets?ipGLN=1234&senderGLN=1234&app_id=3cea2db2&TIMESTAMP=2012-12-06T13:08:02Z"
    Dim Hash() As Byte = SignMessage("6b904a0c5ceefa991b2ebc9cfec202b", testString)
    MsgBox(System.Convert.ToBase64String(Hash, 0, Hash.Length))

End Sub
```

Comment: which crypto library are you using? Is it [crypto-js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) or is it node [crypto](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_cipher)?

Comment: CryptoJS is the library.

Comment: Your generated hash key example seem to be incorrect. When I ran the data and key on this online [tool](http://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output) and [this](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en) it generated a totally different string

Comment: I tried both of those tools but even then that didnt get the result the example shows..

Comment: I made a jsfiddle to run the same hash and the result is not what the example show [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu4ryapg/). My guess is the input "data" is not actually the whole URI string but just bit of data in some order.